# Redirect any directory to another directory

Tags: html, apache, redirect, directory

I want to redirect all directories to another directory.

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/my/cool/link
```

should redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/xyz
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take the time to read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is easier for use to help when we are able to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you wish to redirect all directories on the server to one specific directory?

If that's the case, try something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xyz
```

Comment: @Mark no problem.